# Chart from 2 columns of data

Tags: python, charts

I have 2 columns of data which are comma delimited. eg below -

Time,DataSent

00:00:02,1635807

00:00:11,7153658

00:00:19,31766

00:00:27,31319

00:00:35,30179

How can I use python to chart one against the other?

Comment: Do you mean to plot ?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Usually use pandas for creating charts in python.
One way to do that with your data structure:

```
import pandas as pd

string = 'Time,DataSent 00:00:02,1635807 00:00:11,7153658 00:00:19,31766 00:00:27,31319 00:00:35,30179'
cols = ''.join(string.split()[0]).split(',')
data = ','.join(string.split()[1:]).split(',')
col0 = data[::2]
col1 = [ds for ds in data if ':' not in ds]
df = pd.DataFrame({cols[0]: col0, cols[1]: col1})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       Time DataSent
0  00:00:02  1635807
1  00:00:11  7153658
2  00:00:19    31766
3  00:00:27    31319
4  00:00:35    30179
```

Comment: Apologies, formatting issues when pasting in values, updated data inserted

Comment: the data is coming from a csv @ofeksr

Comment: use pandas.read_csv('filepath'). for more info: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv